# A word or phrase meaning 'paying an unhealthy amount of attention to something you like/want'.

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The context would be in a romantic pursuit or a job opportunity - you've applied for the job and are waiting to hear back from them - you're constantly checking your emails, you're calling the receptionist to ask why they haven't got back to you (way to spoil your chances), etc.

Is there a word or phrase to describe this state.

Example usage might be a friend saying:

> I think you're [over focusing] on this opportunity here. Maybe it'll all work out well - but in the meantime you should divert your attention somewhere else.

Comment: "Obsession" and the Freudian term "fixation" are often used with that meaning: I think you're obsessing/ fixating [over focusing]  on/ over this opportunity here.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Obsessing fits generally - but I'm wondering if there's a more specific term to relates to this 'excited about a new opportunity' context. Obsessing would also apply to a stalker - but it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: The "in" verb is "to fixate"/"fixating".

Comment: @HotLicks - good answer. You should post it.

Comment: hmmmm interesting

Comment: I do like fixated better than in the previous question .. and this question is slightly different ... albeit slightly.  While the OP has shown some good faith, what is still missing, an what would be interesting in the examination of closely related words, would be how much the speaker wanted to choose a word that painted the nature of the ~cause~ is it a clinical issue like "obsessed",  more on the tunnel vision or preoccupation of fixation.. or perhaps, a more mystical notion like "bewitched" even ?  in those flavors language gets interesting

Comment: while 'bewitched' is unlikely here, if the job were such a dream job that it would change self image... the chance of romance and glamor of hollywood .. even if in the accounting department,  for a person applying from the receivables department in a poultry supply company in Peoria.. would 'mesmerized' apply ?  hard to say.. but  certainly suggestions in the previous question ascetic wouldn't.. and again, the spirit of the engrossment was somewhat alluded to in the dictionary answers given there for 'faithfully', 'singlemindedly' and 'unswervably'